# Transaction error "SafeERC20: low-level call failed'"

Tags: solidity, transactions, staking, transferfrom, synthetix

Hi I am trying to make a call to a smart contract function as defined below-

```js
function stake(uint256 amount) external nonReentrant notPaused updateReward(msg.sender) {
   require(amount > 0, "Cannot stake 0");
   _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
   _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
   stakingToken.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
   emit Staked(msg.sender, amount);
}
```

I have provided approval to send tokens and still I am getting a error when trying to call the staking function-

**"Fail with error 'SafeERC20: low-level call failed"**

This particular error is defined in the SafeERC20 library under the following function-

```js
function callOptionalReturn(IERC20 token, bytes memory data) private {
  // We need to perform a low level call here, to bypass Solidity's  return data size checking mechanism, since we're implementing it ourselves.
  // A Solidity high level call has three parts:
  // 1. The target address is checked to verify it contains contract code
  // 2. The call itself is made, and success asserted
  // 3. The return value is decoded, which in turn checks the size of the returned data.

  require(address(token).isContract(), "SafeERC20: call to non-contract");
  (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = address(token).call(data);

  require(success, "SafeERC20: low-level call failed'");
  if (returndata.length > 0) {
  // Return data is optional
  require(abi.decode(returndata, (bool)), "SafeERC20: ERC20 operation did not succeed");
}
```